# CoTURN Usage Statistics

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

I am still a bit new to the WebRTC world and trying to find my way through. I have succcessfully set up CoTURN, and been able to route calls behind a firewall by using CoTURN. Now I am wondering if it is possible to somehow inspect and possibly visualize usage statistics of CoTURN? I would love to know how many users are utilizing the server at any given time, how much the bandwidth and CPU usage is etc.? I saw details on how to optimize bandwidth and CPU usage in the official docs, but I haven't found any info on actually monitoring the usage. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this question about programming? Maybe it would be better on a site like https://superuser.com/

Comment: Not about programming per se, however,  it seems that WebRTC has a much larger community on SO than on SuperUser (17k+ on SO vs 135 results on SU for the WebRTC keyword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to monitor standard usage statistics like CPU usage, load, bandwidth, etc., you can focus on what's available for your infrastructure. For example in AWS you could have CloudWatch, or in generic Linux deployments export the usage stats with Prometheus and have them presented with Grafana.

For the coturn/TURN specific statistics, then coturn allows to store some metrics in Redis; it's described in https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/turndb/schema.stats.redis

```
Total traffic information is also reported when the allocation is deleted. The keys are
"turn/user/<username>/allocation/<id>/total_traffic" or "turn/user/<username>/allocation/<id>/total_traffic/peer". 
Applications interested in the total amount of traffic per allocation can subscribe to these events as:

    psubscribe turn/realm/*/user/*/allocation/*/total_traffic
    psubscribe turn/realm/*/user/*/allocation/*/total_traffic/peer
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into the traffic information event.